# Running a cron job in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I have a site that i have added ACL to database driven. This requires me to put a guest in the database which has a salt. So i need to insert it through the script. Unfortunately the site needs this in order to run properly because it checks for that. So i decided the easiest way to do this was a cron job and then just run it. This is what i need to run, so i put it in a php file and ran it in the sever cron:
/home/testsite/public_html/application/modules/core/views/scripts/user/usercreate.php

```
Core_Model_User::createUser( array('role_id' => 1, 'login' => 'Guest', 'password' => 'shocks'));
```

I get access denied no matter who i run it as.
Is there a special place to put this in order for it to run? Is there an easier way to do this? I have chmod 777 the file also - doesn't seem to make a difference

thanks

Updated at 1:05 May 2nd

I went a different way with this. I ended up getting the user put in the database but the results were not what i expected. I thought it had to be encrypted.

thanks for your comments.

Comment: Cron is a task scheduler used for running a script at a specific time or repeatedly at specific intervals. Why are you using cron to run this script? Do you need to add a new guest like once a day or something?

Comment: No i just needed to insert a user "Guest" through the system. So actually what i did was in the auth file i put the string in under where it asks to authenticate user and did a "if (!" and added the code there. it only had to run once. It did not do anything i couldn't of done in mysql. I thought it needed to be encrypted, but i guess it didn't. I still have an issue with the ID for some reason. I will post a new question for that.